# Cakephp Form Helper Input's label to place outside of the div

Tags: html, cakephp

I've googled and only found *before after* answer to get this done but that does not fit my problem. I want to move default label element outside of the div.

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('name', array( 'before' => $this->Form->label('Subject:'), 'class' => 'form-control', 'div' => 'col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12')); ?>
```

Output is

```
<div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12 required">
  <label for="StaffSubject:">Subject:</label>
  <input name="data[Staff][name]" class="form-control" maxlength="255" type="text" id="StaffName" required="required">
</div>
```

But I want this output instead

```
<label for="StaffSubject:">Subject:</label>
<div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12 required">
  <input name="data[Staff][name]" class="form-control" maxlength="255" type="text" id="StaffName" required="required">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the best solution for that is to remove the label from your input and added before your input

```
<?php echo $this->Form->label('Subject:');
      echo $this->Form->input('name', array( 
          'label' => false, 
          'class' => 'form-control', 
          'div' => 'col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12'
      )); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('name', array(
    'label'=>'Subject',
    'class' => 'form-control',
    'wrapInput' => 'col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12',
)); ?>
```